# How is user address memory organized?

Tags: linux, process, x86, kernel

I always read that, at any given time, the processor can only run one process at a time. So one and only one process is in state `running`.
However, we can have a number of runnable processes. These are all of these processes who are waiting for the scheduler to schedule their execution.

At any given time, do all these runnable processes exist in user address space? Or has the currently running process in user address space, and it is only once they are scheduled that they are brought back to RAM from disk. In which case, does it mean that the kernel keeps the process task descriptor in its list of all runnable processes even if they are in disk? I guess you can tell I am confused.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking.  Each process has a *separate* address space.

Comment: you mean, within lets sat the 3GB allocated for user address space, each process would have a separate address space? i am wondering because i can see at any given time a large number of running processes on my machine..and if all processes i am running(from a processor perspective: the currently running process and the ones waiting for the scheduler to be assigned)...how can they possible be all loaded to the user address space.?

Comment: There is not **the** user address space.  Each process has its own space.

Comment: Unless memory is getting low, background processes remain in RAM, rather than swap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If CPU supports virtual memory addressing, each process has a unique view of the memory. Two different processes that tries to read from the same memory address, will map to different location in physical memory, unless the memory maps tells otherwize (shared memory, like DLL files are mapped read only like this for instance)

If CPU does not support virtual memory, but only memory protection, the memory from the other processes will be protected away, so that the running process can only access its own memory.

Comment: Can Linux run on a processor that doesn't have support for virtual memory?